# align float and specify precision in string formatting

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have this working test code:

```
In [16]: print "{:>20}{:0.2f}".format("", 34)
                34.00
```

but I would like to do it with just one argument in format, how do I write that?

Comment: The formating width is to limit the size of the filling of a variable. You want to always have 20 blank spaces. `' '*20 + '{:0.2f}'.format(34)`

Comment: I want the spaces + the float to always be 20 wide

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Check it. It should be: `'{: 20.2f}'.format(34)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is this what you intended?

```
>>> print "{:>25.2f}".format(34)
                34.00
```

Note, my spaces may be different to yours (the spaces I have is the same distance from your example).

This is what appears for me:

[image]

Comment: Works great with f-strings too.